# Problems posting data forms created by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I now am struggling with this for a couple of days and want to finish it.. Let's explain the html/js/php project. Via select boxes people can choose products and an amount. These products will be inserted via javascript into a basket.

Inside the basket I made an  attribute with a form. In this form the products will be added with javascript with < li > tags. I understood that li tags could not be posted so I made a hidden input for every product. When I try to post the data after that it does not work.

In Opera and Chrome he just gives an empty array and in Firefox he gives an 404 Not found exception on the post. Let's explain some code:

First the **html page**. This is the shop with the products and the basket.

In the **javascript** a fuction get calls when the 'add' button is clickes:
(this is the code that add's the elements to the html)

```
function addProduct() {
    var productAdded = $('<li class="product" name="product' + i + '">' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="p' + i + '"value="' + product + "/" + qty + "/" + price + '" />'    +
        '<div class="product-image">' +
        '<a href="image">' +
        '<img src="images/' + product + '.jpg" alt="placeholder"></a>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="product-details">' +
        '<a style="color: black;">' + product + '</a>' +
        '<span class="price">€ ' + price + '</span><br>' +
        '<div class="quantity">' +
        '<label>Aantal: ' + qty + '</label> <div class="actions">' +
        ' <a href="#0" class="delete-item" >Delete</a></div></div></div></li>');

    cartList.prepend(productAdded);

}
```

[image: Ok. The products get added. The Html that is made looks like this:]

The **Php ** part of the endpage that needs to get the Form data is the following:

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 ">
                                <h3>Bestelling:</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bestellingklant">
                                    <?php

                                    print_r($_POST);


                                    ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

There maybe are some better ways to do this. But I can't see any mistake and I tried a lot of things. It seems though not so difficult. This is the **Error** i get with Firefox:

[image: ERROR]

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you should post the code that doesn't work, not the whole thing.

Comment: indead. Must be something with the js when i make the li attributes? But when you look to the image how he makes it, it looks fine. Not?

Comment: Well, a 404 error means there's a problem either somewhere in your server code, or with your localhost setup. Can that `checkout.php` script return a 404 error at any point?

Comment: No, when it's loaded without a post it just runs

Comment: It would be really good if you could post only the relevant code, and I don't see where you're adding the hidden input you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, i will delete some irrelevant code. I just want that evrything was clear. And yes, the input is added.